# Converting SQL Query into JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json

How would I convert this query into JSON?

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT group_concat(q SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') 
FROM 
(
SELECT distinct
  concat("select pr.id as 'Practice ID', pr.name as 'Practice Name', l.id as 'Location ID', l.name as 'Location Names', l.print_token as 'Print Tokens', concat(ps.printers, ': ', ps.label) as 'Printer Sets and Printer Names'
from `", table_schema, "`.locations l
join `", table_schema, "`.practices pr on pr.id = l.practice_id
join `", table_schema, "`.printer_sets ps on ps.id = l.practice_id
")  AS q
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE 
    table_schema LIKE 'uat%' 
) b ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by converting a query into JSON? A query is code to execute, JSON is just a representation of data.

Comment: Do you mean the result of executing the dynamic query that you're creating with this code?

Comment: Why would you publish the owners/admins info?

Comment: Or do you want the query that's being created to return JSON? If you're using MySQL 5.7 or newer, you can have it `SELECT JSON_OBJECT(...)`.

Comment: I'm using MySQL workbench. Would JSON still work ? or should I try XML instead?